# Highlight specific words in a sentence with diacritrics

Tags: javascript, regex, diacritics

I am searching for some improvements, particularly in the regex, in the way I highlight specific words in a string. Here is the situation :

- I have keywords into my database stored without any diacritrics,
- The user comes with a string with diatrics,
- I find the matches between the keywords and my string modified so that it does not contain any diacritrics,
- I hightlight the matched words in the original sentence with diacritrics.

---

```
var sentence = "J'eusse été amélioré sans des aigÜs si hauts améliorés et raisonnable. Amélioration réaméliorée";
var word = ['eusse','ameliore','aigu','aimerais']; //Matched keywords extracted from database where there are stored without diacritrics

var new_s = sentence, match, output, nb = 0, index = [];
var new_s_cache = removeDiacritics(sentence).replace("'"," ");

for (var i=0;i<word.length;i++){// For each matched word it stores its position and length in the array called index
          var wordInput = word[i].substr(0,4);
          var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\W)"+wordInput+"(\\w*)(?!\\w)","gi");
          while (match = re.exec(new_s_cache)) {
            index.push([match.index,match[0].length]);
          }
        }
index.sort(); // Sort index so that it highlights word in the right order
        for (var j=0;j<index.length;j++) { //It hightlights the word in the orginal sentence with diatrics
new_s = new_s.substr(0,index[j][0]+1+nb) + "<b>" + new_s.substr(index[j][0]+1+nb,index[j][1]) + "</b>" + new_s.substr(index[j][0]+index[j][1]+1+nb);
            nb = nb + 7; // take into account the "<b></b>" length
        }

output = new_s ;
```

Where am I searching improvements ?

- The regex : I want to catch the similar words to keywords. That's why I took arbitrary the 4 first letters and then run a regex to find the words that contains this 4 letters but it's not optimal. Indeed for instance I'd like to find 'unapproved' when the keyword is 'approve'.
- The idea of the code : the juggle between the original sentence and the one without diacritrics appears to be quite fragile.

Here is the JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qqabomsg/3/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the code works, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic is a better place to ask

Comment: As an aside, you can replace `(?:^|\\W)` and `(?!\\w)` with `\\b` that does  the same in this situation (except that it doesn't match an eventual leading non-word character).

Comment: Thanks ! I did not know it, I posted it on codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118773/highlight-specific-words-in-a-sentence-with-diacritrics